SyncFusion XlsIO reference an entire column
I'm working with XlsIO via c# and trying to create an excel file programmatically. I'm trying to set the NumberFormat for an entire column but when I do
worksheet.Columns[1].CellStyle.NumberFormat = "@"; 

it gives me an "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error. Intellisense offers CellStyle.NumberFormat so it's not an issue with using incorrect code. I was able to work around the issue by doing
worksheet.Range["A1:A1000"].CellStyle.NumberFormat = "@";

but I won't always know how many rows down I should go and it seems a little hokey to pick some arbitrary row number instead of being able to just apply this format to the entire column. Am I misunderstanding the use of .Columns? If so, how do I reference a column without having rows involved?
